# xml name/value to table TSQL

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have following table

```
Id | XML
1    XML1
2    XML2
3    XML3
```

Each XML has structure :

```
<aaa>
  <row name="a" value="1" />
  <row name="b" value="2" />
  <row name="c" value="3" />
</aaa>

<aaa>
  <row name="a" value="3" />
  <row name="b" value="4" />
  <row name="c" value="5" />
</aaa>

<aaa>
  <row name="a" value="10" />
  <row name="b" value="20" />
  <row name="c" value="30" />
</aaa>
```

I'd like to get output table:

```
a | b | c
1   2   3
3   4   5
10  20  30
```

I wrote sth in TSQL but i cant get whole parameters from each xml

```
SELECT [Id], [XML] FROM table


SELECT
[XML].value('(aaa/row//@name)[1]','varchar(20)') AS 'NAME',
[XML].value('(aaa/row//@value)[1]','varchar(20)') AS 'VALUE'
 FROM table
```

Comment: are the number of <row> elements constant, e.g. always 3 as in the example?

Comment: Ok, please check the answer I posted and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of your XML all in one variable and the resulting code to select the fields.

```
DECLARE @xmlIN XML = '<TableData>
    <aaa>
      <row name="a" value="1" />
      <row name="b" value="2" />
      <row name="c" value="3" />
</aaa>
<aaa>
  <row name="a" value="3" />
  <row name="b" value="4" />
  <row name="c" value="5" />
</aaa>
<aaa>
  <row name="a" value="10" />
  <row name="b" value="20" />
  <row name="c" value="30" />
</aaa>
</TableData>'

SELECT t.col.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(25)') [name],  
t.col.value('@value',  'VARCHAR(25)') [Value]
FROM    @xmlIn.nodes('//TableData/aaa/row') AS t (col)
```

Then to get the data in the format that you describe you will have to do some sort of PIVOT.

Comment: its working fine, but how to use this for rows in table? : CREATE TABLE table_name ( Id int, XML xml, ); Insert INTO table_name VALUES ( 1, '<aaa> <row name="a" value="1" /> <row name="b" value="2" /> <row name="c" value="3" /> </aaa>') Insert INTO table_name VALUES ( 2, '<aaa> <row name="a" value="3" /> <row name="b" value="4" /> <row name="c" value="5" /> </aaa>') Insert INTO table_name VALUES ( 3, '<aaa> <row name="a" value="10" /> <row name="b" value="20" /> <row name="c" value="30" /> </aaa>') without writing every row to variable ? –

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
[XML].value('(aaa/row/@value)[1]','varchar(20)') AS a,
[XML].value('(aaa/row/@value)[2]','varchar(20)') AS b,
[XML].value('(aaa/row/@value)[3]','varchar(20)') AS c
FROM table
```